# upload file to sql sever with php

Tags: php, sql, upload

I try to upload file to a database by using php.
Here is my code:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db ='testdb';
// Create connection
mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db("testdb");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $UploadName = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['name'];       
        $UploadTmp =  $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];       
        $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i","",$UploadName);
        if (!$UploadTmp)
         {
            die ("No File Selected, Please Upload Again");          
         } else
         {
            move_uploaded_file($UploadTmp,"uploaded/$UploadName");      
            $url = "http://localhost/uploadandview/uploaded/$UploadName";           
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `videos` VALUE('1','$UploadName','$url')");           
          }}?>
```

But i have a proplem, I can't upload any file mp3/mp4, just only upload file text, such as .doc,pdf, css, etc...
Please help me!

Comment: why you not use another method like rename the filename -> save the files to path  -> save detail renamed filename and/or with detail path + file extension to database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
   <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db ='testdb';
// Create connection
mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db("testdb");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $UploadName = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['name'];       
        $UploadTmp =  $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];       
        $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i","",$UploadName);
        if (!$UploadTmp)
         {
            die ("No File Selected, Please Upload Again");          
         } else
         {
            move_uploaded_file($UploadTmp,"uploaded/".$UploadName);      
            $url = "http://localhost/uploadandview/uploaded/".$UploadName;           
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `videos` VALUE('1','$UploadName','$url')");           

      }} ?>
```

Comment: what is input tage name ?